# Extract random values from arrays and reuse it headers for another request

Tags: arrays, json, global-variables, postman

Post request which gives me around 50 random token values from this post request. Only two are shown below. How should I capture the randomtoken value from this post request output and use it for the next request in the header.

```
[
    {
        "randomtoken": "24d4d-asd124-410b-bdc603",
        "fields": {
            
            "Fields.cardno": "4654654123",
            "Fields.name": "LA",
            "Fields.status": "Started",
            "Fields.value": ""
        }
    },
    {
    "randomtoken": "12d4d-ae424-4s0b-we3c603",
        "fields": {
            "Fields.cardno": "4654654123",
            "Fields.name": "LA",
            "Fields.status": "closed",
            "Fields.value": ""
            }
    }
]
```

Let me know how this works

Comment: So you man an initial request, you get 50 `randomtoken` and you're supposed to make a request for each of those tokens? i.e. 50 more requests? Are each of those requests identical except for the `randomtoken`?

Comment: No the request only restricted to give 50 such random tokens. I want to capture and print on console what are these capture token and card no. Random token and some Fields.status fields.cardno also differs in output rest are same.

Comment: So just to be clear you just want to print to the console `randomtoken` and `Fields.cardno`?

Comment: @socalcheesehead yes `randomtoken` and `Fields.cardno` and captured the variables and used both in next request

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're just looking to print to the console you can do the following:

```
var list = pm.response.json();
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
    console.log("randomtoken: " + list[i].randomtoken);
    console.log("cardno:      " + list[i].fields["Fields.cardno"]);
}
```

If you're also looking to reuse any of the variables in another request say `randomtoken` then you simply do `pm.environment.set("randomtoken", randomtoken)` where `randomtoken` is stored to a variable in the loop.

Keep in mind that if you store `randomtoken` to a variable it will be overwritten on each iteration of the loop so you'll need a strategy to handle that if you're planning on reusing it.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using Test of the POST request and using variables.

In the POST request test, you need to get random token value and save it as an environment variable.

```
pm.test("Get randomToken", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.environment.set("randomToken", jsonData[i].randomtoken); 
    //NOTE: i is only to note that you access the object as an array
});
```

And then in the request where you need to use your token you just go to the headers tab and add a key and for value put `{{randomToken}}`.

Comment: There's no loop in that code so I imagine that will fail with a script error as it doesn't know what `i` is defined as.

Comment: @DannyDainton I just put that i to show that he needs to access it as an array. I should note that.

Comment: That's fine but it means nothing on its own and you might as well just add the rest of the code :D What if the person doesn't know how to loop something?

Comment: how to print the in console the captured data with  pm.environment.set("randomToken", jsonData[i].randomtoken)

Comment: tried console.log(pm.environment.set("randomToken", jsonData[0].randomToken)); it says undefined.. @DannyDainton

Comment: This is what I was referring too, it was going to error like that.

Comment: any solution towards this?

Comment: For getting a variable you need to use pm.enviroment.get("randomToken).